# A problem on limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

It seems

> $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{r-1}
>  \sum_{j=0}^{n-r+1} (-1)^j \binom{n-r+1}{j} \frac{1}{r+j+1}$

is $\frac{1}{2}$.  Here's a plot of the function for $n \leq 300$:

[image: The function for n up to 300]

But I can not prove this. Any hints?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $\int_{0}^{1}x^{r+j}dx=\frac{1}{r+j+1}$.

So the sum becomes:

$\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{r-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-r+1}\binom{n-r+1}{j}(-1)^{j}\int_{0}^{1}x^{r+j}dx$

$=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{r-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-r+1}\binom{n-r+1}{j}(-1)^{j}x^{r+j}dx$

$=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{r-1}x^{r}\big(\sum_{j=0}^{n-r+1}\binom{n-r+1}{j}(-x)^{j}\big)dx$

$=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{r-1}x^{r}(1-x)^{n-r+1}dx$

$=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{r=0}^{n-2}\binom{n}{r}x^{r+1}(1-x)^{n-r}dx$

$=\int_{0}^{1}x\sum_{r=0}^{n-2}\binom{n}{r}x^{r}(1-x)^{n-r}dx=\int_{0}^{1}x\big((x+(1-x))^{n}-nx^{n-1}(1-x)-x^{n}\big)dx$

$=\int_{0}^{1}x\big(1-nx^{n-1}+nx^{n}-x^{n}\big)dx=\int_{0}^{1}xdx-n\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}dx+n\int_{0}^{1}x^{n+1}dx-\int_{0}^{1}x^{n+1}dx$

$=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{n+1}+\frac{n}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{-n}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

$=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{n+2}$.

So $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{r-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-r+1}(-1)^{j}\binom{n-r+1}{j}\big(\frac{1}{r+j+1}\big)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Your's is certainly simpler than mine, and we differ in the remainder. I would bet that your's ($1/(n+1)$) is more likely to be correct than mine.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake. Thank you for the correction Marty.

Comment: Sonofagun! I beat the odds.

Comment: @user71352 & Marty Cohen: Thank you very much. This is just awesome.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 8):

$\begin{align}
 S(n)
&=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{r-1}
 \sum_{j=0}^{n-r+1} (-1)^j \binom{n-r+1}{j} \frac{1}{r+j+1}\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{n-2}\binom{n}{r}
 \sum_{j=0}^{n-r} (-1)^j \binom{n-r}{j} \frac{1}{r+j+2}\\
\text{(replace }r \text{ by } n-r)\quad&= \sum_{r=2}^{n}\binom{n}{r}
 \sum_{j=0}^{r} (-1)^j \binom{r}{j} \frac{1}{n-r+j+2}\\
(D \text{ described below) }\quad&= D+\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}
 \sum_{j=0}^{r} (-1)^j \binom{r}{j} \frac{1}{n-r+j+2}\\
\text{(replace } j \text{ by } r-j)\quad&= D+\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}
 \sum_{j=0}^{r} (-1)^{r-j} \binom{r}{j} \frac{1}{n-j+2}\\
\text{(change order of summation) }\quad&= D+\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{r=j}^{n}\binom{n}{r}
  (-1)^{r-j} \binom{r}{j} \frac{1}{n-j+2}\\
\quad&=D+ \sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{n-j+2}\sum_{r=j}^{n}
(-1)^{r}\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{j} \\
\text{ (put } n-r \text{ for } r)\quad&=D+ \sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{n-j+2}
\sum_{r=0}^{n-j}(-1)^{n-r}\binom{n}{n-r}\binom{n-r}{j} \\
\text{ (put } n-j \text{ for } j)\quad&= D+\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n-j}}{j+2}
\sum_{r=0}^{j}(-1)^{n-r}\binom{n}{n-r}\binom{n-r}{n-j} \\
&= D+\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j+2}
\sum_{r=0}^{j}(-1)^{r}\frac{n!(n-r)!}{(n-r)!r!(n-j)!(j-r)!} \\
&= D+n!\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{(n-j)!(j+2)}
\sum_{r=0}^{j}(-1)^{r}\frac{1}{r!(j-r)!} \\
&= D+n!\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j!(n-j)!(j+2)}
\sum_{r=0}^{j}(-1)^{r}\frac{j!}{r!(j-r)!} \\
&= D+\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j+2}
\sum_{r=0}^{j}(-1)^{r}\binom{j}{r} \\
\text{(since }\sum_{r=0}^{j}(-1)^{r}\binom{j}{r}=0 \text{ for }j > 0)\quad
&= D+\frac{1}{2}\\
\end{align}
$

$D=
-\sum_{r=0}^1\binom{n}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{r} (-1)^{r-j} \binom{r}{j} \frac{1}{n-j+2}
$.

If $r=0$,
$\binom{n}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{r}(-1)^{r-j} \binom{r}{j} \frac{1}{n-j+2}
=\binom{n}{0}\binom{0}{0} \frac{1}{n+2}
=\frac{1}{n+2}
$.

If $r=1$,
$\binom{n}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{r} (-1)^{r-j} \binom{r}{j} \frac{1}{n-j+2}
=\binom{n}{1}\left(-\binom{1}{0} \frac{1}{n+2}+\binom{1}{1} \frac{1}{n+1}\right)
=n\left(-\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)
=n\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)
=\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$.

So $D
=-\frac{1}{n+2}
-\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)}
=\frac{-(n+1)-n}{(n+1)(n+2)}
=\frac{-2n-1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
=-\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$.

Therefore
$S(n) = \frac12-\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$.

OMG!!!!!

I can't believe that
all this algebra
came up with something that
looks correct!

Note:
to compare my remainder
with user71352's,
$\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{1}{n+1}
=\frac{2n+1-(n+2)}{(n+1)(n+2)}
=\frac{n-1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
$.

A computation could decide which is correct,
but, considering the relative complexity of the solutions,
mine has a higher chance of being wrong.

(Added later)

But it wasn't.
Surprisingly (to me),
mine was correct.

Feels good.

I knew it would.

Comment: Shades of James Brown.<grin>

Comment: According to my answer, your remainder is correct.

Comment: And, according to my answer, your remainder is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the $n^\text{th}$ forward difference of $1/x$ is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac1{k+x}=\frac{n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)\dots(x+n)}\tag{1}
$$
To prove $(1)$, apply the [Heaviside Method for Partial Fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) to the right hand side, as is done in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/480958) with $f(j)=1$.

Use $(1)$ with $n\mapsto n-r+1$, then set $x=r+1$ to get the first step below:
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{r-1}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-r+1}(-1)^j\binom{n-r+1}{j}\frac1{r+j+1}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{r-1}
\frac{(n-r+1)!\,r!}{(n+2)!}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\frac{r}{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&=\frac12\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ gives $\frac12$.

Comment: Very nice. *Much* simpler than mine. Upvoted.

Comment: @martycohen: I saw the repeated difference of $1/x$ and have used $(1)$ before. It comes in useful with the [Euler Series Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler.27s_transform) as well.