# How to show the following identity?

Tags: permutations, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I need to show the following identity. Any lead will be helpful and appreciated. Thanks in advance.

$$\binom{n}{m} m \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{\binom{m-1}{i}(-1)^i}{n-m+1+i}=1$$ for fixed $n$ and $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{i}\frac{(-1)^i}{n-m+i+1}=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{i}(-1)^i x^{n-m+i}\,dx $$
hence by the binomial theorem
$$ S = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{1-x}\left(-1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{m}\,dx $$
and by setting $x=\frac{1}{z}$, then $z=t+1$, we get:
$$ S = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{(z-1)^{m-1}}{z^{n+1}}\,dz = \color{red}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^{m-1}}{(1+t)^{n+1}}\,dt}. $$
The last integral is easy to compute by integration by parts, or by using [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).
At last we have:
$$ S = \frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n-m+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)} = \frac{m!(n-m)!}{m\cdot n!} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{m\binom{n}{m}}}$$
as wanted.

Comment: Thank you Jack ! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ArnabKoley: you're welcome (but an upvote woud be kind if this answer actually helped you :) )

Comment: I went for upvote. But it says voters should have less than 15 reputations. I am new to this forum. Even if I can't caste my vote, I must say you helped me a lot. Thank you once again :) :)

Answer (score 0):

The following 
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912720/) 
proves that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{x+k} (-1)^k {n\choose k}
= n! \times \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{x+q}.$$

Put $n=m-1$ and $x=n-m+1$ to get

$$(m-1)! \times \prod_{q=0}^{m-1} \frac{1}{n-m+1+q}
\\ = (m-1)! \times \frac{(n-m)!}{n!}
= \frac{1}{m} \times {n\choose m}^{-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you @MarkoRiedel. The MSE link is an useful one ! Thanks for your help.