# I'm trying to integrate this function, but i have no idea how continue

Tags: integration, factorial, partial-fractions

so here what i want to integrate

$$
r(x)= \frac{n!}{(x(x + 1).....(x + n))}  
$$
and here what i have done, i will thankful for tips

i have started with partial fractions
$$
r(x) =  \frac{A_0}{x} + \frac{A_1}{x+1}+\frac{A_2}{x+2} + ... +\frac{A_n}{x+n}
$$

then i get
$$
n! = A_0(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)+A_1 x(x+2)...(x+n) + A_2 x(x+1)(x+3)...(x+n) + ... + A_n x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n-1)
$$
here were i stuck and i don't know how to continue, how to find the value of A so i could easliy then integrate the function

Comment: This should help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1912720/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%20%5Cfrac%7Bn!%7D%7Bx(x%20%2B%201)%20%5Ccdots%20(x%20%2B%20n)%7D%24)

Comment: You could try the partial fractions with $n=1,2,3$ and see if you spot a pattern

Comment: @MartinR i have seen the link, but it get more complicated, first of all, if i used the fromula, before using it i will need to prove it , shich doens't really help, and secondly this might be me but i get more lost and don't know how it could help me. if possible could you explain more